# Xcode playground error "unterminated '/*' comment"

Tags: xcode, markdown, swift-playground

I'm facing a very strange behavior of Xcode markup comments. Just for fun open a new playground and type this:

```
print("It works")

/*:
 }
 */

print("It can't be executed : unterminated comment")
```

The second part can't be executed because of the `}` character... If you remove the `:` it works  without crashing, but it transforms the markdown comment into classical comment, that's not what I'm looking for...

It really seems to be a plain good old fashioned bug, but if someone knows a workaround to display this kind of markup, I'd be grateful:

```
/*:
 Function declaration:

     func functionName(param1: Type1, param2: Type2) -> ReturnType {
         ...
         return ...
     }

 * Note: Parameters and function names are `lowerCamelCase`.
 */
```

Thanks in advance...

(In the mean time, I'll send a feedback...)

I'm using Xcode 11.3.1 (11C504) on Catalina 10.15.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in fact I found a workaround... I'm using this unicode character `｝` instead of `}` and it visually kind of works...

[image: Curly bracket workaround]

At least, that will do for what I want...